# Modify existing Angular function from angular/core package

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, monkeypatching

I am wondering if it is possible to monkey patch an existing function from angular/core package so that the altered function is used always instead of the original one. To clarify I am not calling the said function directly, instead it is called by angular itself.

To be more specific I would like to make changes to this [function](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/util.ts#L30) but without making pull request or forking angular. For the sake of simplicity let's say that I want to add console.log('changed') to the end of the said function without changing anything else.

Comment: i am not quite sure if this is allowed ,it is a framework not a library

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not modifying functions in an existing package. Instead either: 1) write your own function that wraps the existing function, or 2) copy-paste the existing function to your own code and then modify it there.

Comment: Thank you for response. Would either of those two options have in consequence that "original" function is replaced with the modified one across the angular package? To clarify, I want other parts of angular that call said function to call my modified version.

Comment: Maybe we are too focused on specifics.. what is it your real goal here? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that not to modify the internal functions of angular because you don't know where Angular is using that function internally and it is difficult to manage the changes in the internal function when you are working in team. If you want to change the functionality for your application then extend that class or implement the interface as per your usage.

Comment: I am aware that it is not recommended but still, is it possible? I am not directly using said function in my application, instead angular itself is using it during the change detection.

Comment: Yes you can change that function in the src folder in the node modules but then after you have to manage the same copy of the node modules across the different developers. If explain a little more which function you want to change or what functionality you want to achieve then may be I can explain in more details

Comment: As far as I know source code of angular is not in node_modules, just the .d.ts declaration files so this is not possible. I linked to the function in original post and for the sake of simplicity let's say that I want to add console.log('test') to the said function.

Answer (score 0):

You can `extend` an existing angular core class or interface by importing from the source module. But you cannot modify or override a function which is exported from the source module.

you can create a class like below and export it. Then inside the class you can create a wrapper function which calls the original imported angular function.

```
export class ExampleClass{

  // create your wrapper function here
}
```

Then in the pages where you want your function to be called instead directly calling the angular function , import your class like below

`import {ExampleClass} from <your ts file>`

You can then call your custom method in that page.

Comment: So what you are saying is that essentially it's not possible to do what I want to do?

Comment: About the edit that you made, I am not calling the function directly from my application. Instead the said function is called by angular itself during change detection.

Comment: Then it's pretty risky to do because the entire change detection is handled by angular core .

Comment: I am well aware that it is pretty risky, but is it possible?